# JavaFX - Force input from TextField to be uppercase

Tags: javafx, textfield, scenebuilder, uppercase

I use javafx and scene builder. I want to make textfield letters(no matter if user caps lock is off or on) to be only uppercase.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) on your TextField like:

```
yourtextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>((change) -> {
            change.setText(change.getText().toUpperCase());
            return change;
        }));
```